# Temporary files are not deleted after Junit test

Tags: java, file-io, junit

I have a test where  I want the files I create in Junit test to be deleted after the test is done , I use junit.rules.TemporaryFolder to do this .

This is how my test goes :

```
public class FileUtilityIntegrationTest {

    static TemporaryFolder _tempFolder2;
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testCreateZip() throws IOException {
        File zipFile = testFolder.newFile("fileName.zip");
        File tempDir = testFolder.newFolder("tempDir");
        File innerFile = new File(tempDir, "testFile.txt");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(innerFile)) {
            fos.write("this is in testFile".getBytes());
        }
        FileUtility.createZip(tempDir, zipFile);
        assertTrue(TestUtil.zipFileContainsAndNotEmpty(zipFile, innerFile.getName()));
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        _tempFolder2 = testFolder;
        System.out.println(_tempFolder2.getRoot().exists()); //true
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println(_tempFolder2.getRoot().exists()); //true
    }
}
```

As you can see the files/folders are not deleted after the test is done. I also trying explicity closing `fos` that didn't work either

Here is the actual method I am trying to test:

```
public static void createZip(File inputDirectory, File zipFile) throws IOException {
  classLogger.debug("Creating Zip '" + zipFile.getPath() + "'");

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)){

        // create zip file from files in directory
        for (File file : inputDirectory.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                classLogger.debug("File to be zipped: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                addToZipFile(file, zos);
            }
        }
        zos.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        classLogger.error("Error processing zip file: " + zipFile.getPath(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: The API Docs says `The TemporaryFolder Rule allows creation of files and folders that should be deleted when the test method finishes (whether it passes or fails). Whether the deletion is successful or not is not checked by this rule. No exception will be thrown in case the deletion fails.`. Perhaps you try to call `tempFolder.delete()` in your `@After`method manually?

Comment: Yes deleting them manually is something I plan to do if I am not able to find out why Junit doesn't delete them automatically ,

Answer (score 0):

Test rulle call applyAll method which call after your junit after method .
It is call on finally block .So please check the temDir location if physically removed or not.Check  `File tempDir`field for temp location

```
before();
                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                } finally {
                    after();
                }

private static Statement applyAll(Statement result, Iterable<TestRule> rules,
            Description description) {
        for (TestRule each : rules) {
            result = each.apply(result, description);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I do check the physical folder/files, its not removed there either

Comment: Can go to the Temporaryfolder class and debug point see in delete method why it is not working.

Comment: yes thats a good idea, but I think I did found it out tho ,seems like I was having a stream open , which was causing this